# How to independently produce 3D Movies when 3D-TV's are discontinued?

Tags: post-production, 3d

Big TV-Screen companies like LG, Sony, Samsung and Sharp have announced that they'll discontinue to produce 3D-TV's.

What impact does it have to small independent film producers, that produce 3D films?
How are you able to set up and test your 3D footage, before showing in in Theaters and festivals?

Do you have to keep using "old" monitors and screens or will Screens in "the normal" (affordable) price range still be avavable to the public? (Does a company have annunced to keep continuing screens no matter what?)

Comment: What 'small, independent film producer' produces in 3D?

Comment: There are a variety of film producers doing that. There are even 3D rigs as far back as the GoPro Heron 2 (for action cams). And if you have the knowlege and 2 idenical cameras, virtually everyone can do it. However you need a 3D Monitor to composit it.

Comment: @MoritzLost The kind who produces scantily clad content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some are using VR headsets, some work with anaglyph glasses. With some plug-ins (such as the [Dashwood 360 VR Toolbox](http://dashwood3d.com), as one example), you can use popular headsets like the Oculus Rift. But many will convert the left and right eye to red/cyan and blend them so you can use those silly paper glasses from your childhood. Simple, but effective!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is indeed quite late.

If you don't specifically have to use a TV, you may do with a projector. There are projectors with 3D stereoscpy support, such as the Optoma UHD506 which I use. These projectors advertise support for "Bluray and PC 3D", which I'm assume it's some kind of marketing term.

However, they don't convert left-right pictures into 3D imagery, instead, some of these DLP-Link require the HDMI source to output at 120Hz, with each eye getting 60 frames every second.

Optoma provided glasses that can switch eye when the left-right signal goes out of sync.

Also, these 3D modes are often only available at 1080p resolution.

Finally, if you want to play a 3D movies on these projectors, you need some software like [Bino3D](https://bino3d.org/).

I've also written the [Studio Media Player](https://github.com/dannyniu/Studio-Media-Player) for Mac using the Swift programming language for my own use. Because I don't have the finacial motive to enroll in Apple developer program, I can't offer that as an App, so you need to compile it using Xcode if you were to use my player.